# Place order automatically

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Can you have a price line and have script place order long or short when the bars hit that price.

If the price (ticks) are moving up to my price where I want to get short, can pine script place the order for me.

Answer (score 0):

User drawn objects are not accessible in pine-script.

You can draw your line programmatically and see if the price is crossing it.

Pinescript cannot place orders directly. You might be able to do that using alerts with webhooks.